# What is the reason for seemingly inconsistent sizes of pointers and struct types?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, sizeof

On my machine, the relevant sizes are:
`sizeof(char) == 1`, `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(char*) == 8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person{
    char *name;
    int age;
}Person;

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(Person): %d\n", sizeof(Person)); //-> 16 bytes
    Person *person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("sizeof(person): %d\n", sizeof(person)); //-> 8 bytes ( Why 8 and not 16? )

    char buffer[32];
    printf("sizeof(buffer): %d\n", sizeof(buffer)); //-> 32 bytes
    person -> name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    printf("sizeof(person->name): %d\n", sizeof(person->name)); //-> 8 bytes ( Why 8 and not 32? )

    return 0;
}
```

I know that `sizeof(Person) == 16` because of padding, but I don't understand the following. 
If `sizeof(Person) == 16`, why `sizeof(person) == 8` and not 16? 
And if `sizeof(buffer) == 32`, why `sizeof(person->name) == 8` and not 32?

Comment: `person` is 8 bytes cuz it's a pointer and the same goes for `person->name`.

Comment: @PSkocik That is practically an answer. Will you make one? If not, why not? Would you mind me making one with basically the same content?

Comment: @Yunnosch Feel free to copy it and post it as your answer, lol :D

Comment: Not "copy"; I said "basically same content". Trying to do a little more explaining and formatting.

Comment: I feel sure there's a 'classic' answer (with 384 upvotes) to this. But I've search and can't find it.

Comment: Aside: please use `%zu` to match `sizeof`. Again, it's a matter of size, `%d` might expect a 32-bit argument, but `sizeof` might supply a 64-bit value.

Comment: @WeatherVane if I use ```%zu``` I get a warning: ```unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]| ```

Comment: You'll perhaps need a more recent compiler :-) If you don't have `%zu` I suggest using `%llu` and cast the operand: `(unsigned long long)sizeof(buffer)`

Comment: @BUG That means your compiler's obsolete in regards to this feature (your libc probably too). You can also cast to the sizeof expression to `(int)` and keep the `"%d"` (for these guaranteed to be small sizes, `int` is definitely fine, `long long unsigned` + `"%llu"` should be safe in a more context-free fashion).

Comment: @PSkocik that cast seems to work fine for me for now - no warnings or errors. I will try in the future to update my compiler to be able to use ```%zu```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters to output an object of the type `size_t`  you shall use the conversion specifier `zu`

```
printf("sizeof(Person): %zu\n", sizeof(Person));
                        ^^^
```

> I don't understand the following: If sizeof(Person) == 16, why
> sizeof(person) == 8 and not 16?

The name `Person` denotes the structure

```
typedef struct person{
    char *name;
    int age;
}Person;
```

An object of this type occupies 16 bytes.

The name `person` declared like

```
Person *person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

denotes a pointer. This pointer occupies 8 bytes and points to a memory allocated for an object of the type Person that occupies 16 bytes.

That is `sizeof( Person )` and `sizeof( Person * )` that is equivalent to `sizeof( person )` are two different expressions.

> And if sizeof(buffer) == 32, why sizeof(person->name) == 8 and not 32?

Again the  name `name` has a pointer type and occupies 8 bytes. It is a data member of the structure `person` declared like

```
char *name;
```

This pointer points to a dynamically allocated memory that occupies 32 bytes.

Pay attention to that the size of a pointer does not depend on whether it points to a single object or to the first element of an array. That is you can allocate memory for a very big array but nevertheless the size of the pointer pointing to the allocated memory will not be changed depending on the size of the allocated memory.

Consider for example

```
int a[10];

int *p = a;

int b[10000];

int *q = b;
```

In this example the pointers p and q have the same size. You could write for example

```
int a[10];

int *p = a;

int b[10000];

p = b;
```

The size of the pointer `p` will not be changed after the last assignment.

Answer (score 6):

Because, as `sizeof(char *)`, `sizeof(person)` returns the size of a pointer. And in your case, a pointer to a struct (here to a Person struct) is of size 8.

And `sizeof(person->name)` returns the size of a pointer on a char as `name` is defined as a `char *`.

`buffer` is not a pointer, it is an array. The compiler knows it and `sizeof(buffer)` returns the size of the array, even through there is some similarities between the name of an array and a pointer, they are not treated the same.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment by  PSkocik.

`person` is a pointer, same size as pointer to char. same for `person->name`.
`struct person` is a type, same size as `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a core concept in C. It's your breakthrough moment when you get it things start making sense.

A pointer is an address. I can have the address of your house written on a piece of paper and the paper doesn't need to be the size of your house.

I'm not being silly the way we use 'address' in C is closely associated to that real-life concept. But C pointers (addresses) are places in memory. They're represented by the value of some fixed number of bytes.

OK, so the postal system identifies your house by block of characters.

In computers we identify locations in memory be a sequence of bytes. Yes, we use bytes to store the location of other bytes.

`malloc(sizeof(Person))` return the address of (a pointer to) a block of memory large enough to hold a `Person` structure.

It didn't return the block. That's 'somewhere' identified by, can be 'found', accessed, written to and read from using the address.

An pointer/address isn't the thing it's a reference to a thing. Here using `reference` in the broad computing sense not the slightly narrower sense it's used in C++.

Your machine clearly uses 64-bit addressing. There are 8-bits in a standard byte and and a size of 8 amounts to 64 bits.

The C Standard in some parts talks about pointers functionally. It tells you applying `&` to suitable expression returns a pointer that can be de-referenced by `*` or `->` to get to the thing or part of it respectively. But it also talks about the 'address-of' operator (being `&`) and I believe why it uses ampersand which is a stylised 'a'.

To answer the questions.
`sizeof(person)` is 8 bytes because that's the address of 16 bytes that `malloc()` has set aside for you to store 16 bytes as requested (the size of a `Person` object).

The answer regarding `person->name` is similar. It's the address **of** 16 bytes not **itself** 16 bytes.

Add `printf("person: %p\n",(void*)person);` it will print out the address.
It's implementation defined how it comes out but it's almost certainly going to be like `person: 0x7ffca93ce784` (but a different hex value).
That won't change if you change the values in it (e.g. `person->age=50;`).

Do take heed of that advice that you need to use `%zu` to output a size.
Also get into the habit of calling `free(person);` when you've finished with memory you allocated. Render unto `free()` anything `malloc()` rendered unto thee.
If not that memory you were allocated can't be reused. That won't affect this little program. But it will become an issue later.

I'd say formalising the distinction between a reference and its referant is a key Computing notion. The something that identifies a thing and the thing. No one has an issue that their name refers to them but isn't them. But somehow when it all gets abstracted into computing you need to consciously understand the distinction more clearly.

All programming languages have this and useful ones have some notion of pointer-like things. In Java it's an Object Variable. That's a reference to an object. Not the object. It even lets slip and if you abuse want gives you a `NullPointerException`. But I thought Java didn't have pointers! Secret.

---

The question you'll ask soon is why `sizeof(Person)` is 16 but `sizeof(char*)+sizeof(int)` is 12. What (you will ask) are the other 4 bytes doing? I won't go into it but there may be 'dead' bytes in a structure to make things line up nicely. Many computers need (or work more efficiently) if things like pointers and ints are stored at addresses with some low bits set to 0 - it's called alignment and it's a hardware thing!